# SharePoint Document Library Column Header filtering issue

Tags: document-library, filter

I have a document library with close to 5000 docs. When signed in as a site collection admin, applying filtering via column header on a column that contains only 20 unique values works fine. However, when logged on as a site user with lesser privileges, clicking on the same column header takes very long, sometimes 5 minutes to render the filter options box. The document library applies unique permissions to each item.

My questions are:

1. Why does it take so long for the filter options box to appear when logged on as a non site collection admin.
2. I want to enable, by default, column headers to display filter choices as shown in this image: [link](https://public.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pFGSmiz64o8tVAkFnUnkXKbIWiwcjKDDv8f3Wf9JvUAHaF57q4_xr4hNm_TmQg7th/ShowFiltersColumnHeader.png?psid=1). How can i achieve this. Some posts on internet suggest to remove

`<xsl:if test="$dvt_adhocmode = 'filter'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">`

in DVWP to enable filter choices to display by default. but i do not know how to achieve this. SharePoint designer doesn't seem to help.

Thanks for your help.